# How can i define a CHECK CONSTRAINT to enforce the rule of minimum 3 instances of a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Table1(col1,col2,col3)
```

I want to define a CHECK CONSTRAINT that enforce a rule that there must be a minimum of 3 instances of a value in a column.

Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Athletes_Participations
ADD CONSTRAINT Check_participations CHECK (count(AID) >= 3)
```

The error message that get is:

> An aggregate may not appear in a computed column expression or check constraint.

this is what i've tried:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CHECKINSTANCES()  
RETURNS int  
AS   
BEGIN  
   DECLARE @retval int  
   SELECT @retval = COUNT(AID) FROM tbl1  
   RETURN @retval  
END; 
GO  
ALTER TABLE tbl1  
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_INS CHECK (dbo.CHECKINSTANCES() >= 3 );  
GO
```

Comment: You can't enforce this with a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` alone. You would either need to create a scalar function and call that from the `CONSTRAINT` (can have performance impacts) or implement a **set based** trigger that checks the data after an `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.

Comment: can you post an example of this kind of function please?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the first instance of that value is inserted into the table though?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) has plenty of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples); the first one of a scalar function (which is what you would need if you went down that route).

Comment: I *assume* that when they `INSERT` data with a new value of `AID`, the `INSERT` contains at least 3 rows with that value, @DavidG . Of course, if they want to `INSERT` 2 rows and `UPDATE` a 3rd, they are "knackered".

Comment: @Larnu Sure, it just feels awfully... flaky I guess. It's an odd requirement.

Comment: I don't disagree with that, @DavidG . ;)

Comment: I agree with all of you, but this is the requirment. i'm posting a function that i have tried

Comment: Check constraints are row-based, not table-based. Using hacks like functions to work around this is not recommended, because the engine cannot guarantee the check is actually enforced when you start doing that. This would have to be done through a trigger and/or forcing inserts and updates to go through a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comments, this is messy. You can't do this with a `CONSTRAINT` alone, which means you either need to use a `TRIGGER` or a scalar function. I dislike using scalar functions in `CONSTRAINT`s, they have been known to tank performance, so I'm using a `TRIGGER` here.

Note that either implementation comes with caveats. Firstly, if you are inserting new rows you **cannot** insert them one by one. This will fail (as the first row will fail the pseudo `CONSTRAINT`). You won't be able to do task like `UPDATE` 1 row to have the value of new value, and `INSERT` 2 new rows either (with the same new value) as when the first statement completes the error will be thrown (due to there only being 1 or 2 rows). You'd have to use "proxy rows" to get around that. I demonstrate this below.

All in all, I suggest a design rethink.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (col1 int NOT NULL,
                            col2 varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                            col3 date NOT NULL);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.YourTable_Min3Col1 ON dbo.YourTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM dbo.YourTable YT
               WHERE YT.Col1 IN (SELECT i.col1
                                 FROM inserted i
                                 UNION ALL
                                 SELECT d.col1
                                 FROM deleted d)
                GROUP BY Col1
                HAVING COUNT(Col1) < 3)
        --Use an error code appropriate for you
        THROW 79845, N'A check rule in the trigger ''YourTable_Min3Col1'' has failed. Less than 3 instances of a value of in the column ''Col1'' exist. The statement has been aborted.', 16; 
END;
GO
--Succeeds
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (col1,
                           col2,
                           col3)
VALUES(1,'abc',GETDATE()),
      (1,'def',GETDATE()),
      (1,'xyz',GETDATE());
GO
--Fails
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (col1,
                           col2,
                           col3)
VALUES(2,'abc',GETDATE()),
      (2,'def',GETDATE());
GO
--Succeeds
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (col1,
                           col2,
                           col3)
VALUES(3,'abc',GETDATE()),
      (3,'def',GETDATE()),
      (3,'xyz',GETDATE()),
      (3,'opq',GETDATE());
GO
--Fails, despite that at the end of the batch there would be 3 rows with a value of 4
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (col1,
                           col2,
                           col3)
VALUES(4,'abc',GETDATE()),
      (4,'def',GETDATE());

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET col1 = 4
WHERE col1 = 3
  AND col2 = 'opq';
GO
--Use a "proxy" row to enforce it works
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (col1,
                           col2,
                           col3)
VALUES(4,'abc',GETDATE()),
      (4,'def',GETDATE()),
      (4,'def','19000101');

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET col1 = 4
WHERE col1 = 3
  AND col2 = 'opq';

DELETE
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE Col1 = 4
  AND Col3 = '19000101';

GO
--Fails, would reduce below 3
DELETE
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE col1 = 1
  AND col2 = 'xyz';
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc00b18266b473d3ffb257ae0b0aea18)

Comment: `COUNT(Col1)` does not itself group, you need `GROUP BY Col1 HAVING COUNT(*) < 3` see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=43b2ed3c98201b87df6e241c72253516

Comment: Nice catch, @Charlieface . As all the examples I did only involved 1 value of `Col1` I missed that.